# How to implement IBsonSerializer in dotnet

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, serialization, deserialization

I am working with MongoDB, and I need to create a serializer that can be injected as a **provider** without having to decorate the class with BsonSerializerAttribute.

I register as a provider like this:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(SexType), new SexTypeSerializer());
```

I always get an exception because the **object value** is always null in this method.

How can I solve this problem?

```
public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
```

This is the class I implemented.

```
    public class SexTypeSerializer : IBsonSerializer<SexType>
    {
        public Type ValueType
        {
            get { return typeof(SexType); }
        }

        public SexTypeSerializer() { }

        public SexType Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        {
            var value = context.Reader.ReadString();

            return SexType.FromCode(value);
        }

        public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, SexType value)
        {
            BsonSerializer.Serialize(context.Writer, value.Code);
        }

        object IBsonSerializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        {
            return SexType.FromCode(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<string>(context.Reader));
        }

        public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
        {
            if (value is SexType sexType)
            {
                BsonSerializer.Serialize(context.Writer, sexType.Code);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException($"This is not an {nameof(SexType)}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes as per the refactored code below:

```
    public class SexTypeSerializer : SerializerBase<SexType>
    {
        public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, SexType sexType)
        {
            context.Writer.WriteString(sexType.Code);            
        }

        public override SexType Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        {
            var code = context.Reader.ReadString();
            
            return SexType.FromCode(code);
        }
    }
```

And on your Startup.cs use it like this:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new SexTypeSerializer());
```